# Imposible to start PhpStorm 2016.1 after update

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

I've just update PhpStorm to v2016.1 and I can't start it, it is crashing from start...

Here is the error log.

```
Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: cannot create class 'com.jetbrains.php.actions.PhpStormNewProjectStep' [Plugin: com.intellij]
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:194)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.convertStub(ActionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:511)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.getAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.preloadActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:1263)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader.preload(ActionPreloader.java:31)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader$2$1.run(Preloader.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader$2.run(Preloader.java:74)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:520)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.convertStub(ActionManagerImpl.java:154)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:484)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method io/j99/idea/vue/module/VueProjectGenerator.getName must not return null
    at io.j99.idea.vue.module.VueProjectGenerator.getName(VueProjectGenerator.java:26)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ProjectSettingsStepBase.<init>(ProjectSettingsStepBase.java:62)
    at com.jetbrains.php.actions.PhpStormProjectSpecificSettingsStep.<init>(PhpStormProjectSpecificSettingsStep.java:16)
    at com.jetbrains.php.actions.PhpStormNewProjectStep$Customization.createProjectSpecificSettingsStep(PhpStormNewProjectStep.java:42)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.AbstractNewProjectStep$Customization.getActions(AbstractNewProjectStep.java:112)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.AbstractNewProjectStep$Customization.getActions(AbstractNewProjectStep.java:99)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.AbstractNewProjectStep.<init>(AbstractNewProjectStep.java:65)
    at com.jetbrains.php.actions.PhpStormNewProjectStep.<init>(PhpStormNewProjectStep.java:15)
    ... 22 more
```

Any idea

Comment: Have you tried moving your plugins folder to somewhere else and opening the phpstorm?

Comment: it worked! so, what I am supposed to do with my plugin folder?

Comment: Oh, I see I had some red plugin, I guess it is red because of incompatibility. Please put your comment as answer!

Comment: yes it sounds like. I would reinstall them if they are not a lot and delete the folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your plugins is incompatible with new 2006.1 version -- please either disable it or remove the plugin file completely.

The faulty plugin is **vue-for-idea**.

Comment: That crashed on me recently too with the latest EAP.

Comment: I had the same problem with the `Vue.js` plugin.

Comment: Obviousily, I couldn't open PhpStorm to remove the plugin, as PhpStorm didn't open... I had go go to "C:\Users\Jan Sverre\.PhpStorm2016.1\config\plugins" and remove "vue-for-idea.jar"